# phpunit debugging only going into phpunit.phar file

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm, xdebug

I’m attempting to debug unit tests using XDebug through PHPStorm.

The tests run on the server correctly.
When I turn on debugging in PHPStorm and have remote debugging enabled on the server, PHPStorm will open up the phpunit file and tell me that is the line it is on.
If I click continue, it never reaches the breakpoint I have in my unit test; which I’m 100% positive is being hit.

I have added the following to my: /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9020
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.extend_info=1
xdebug.show_local_vars=1
xdebug.remote_host=x.x.x.x
```

I run the test with this:

```
function debugTest() {
   php -d xdebug.remote_enable=1 `which phpunit` `pwd`/$1
}
```

`$ debugTest myclassTest.php`

Honestly, I’m not sure what to share from my PHPStorm setup that would be helpful, but if anything would be helpful, I can send it along.

Comment: Don't know why you need that `debugTest` kind of stuff. Anyway: have you tried debugging over SSH? Official manual: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Running+PHPUnit+tests+over+SSH+on+a+remote+server+with+PhpStorm

Comment: Have the same problem!

Comment: I forgot I had this question. I did get it figured out, so I’ll have to take some time to write out what I did. There really isn’t much to it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to improve the test execution:

- Use the 'PHPUnit' or 'PHPUnit on Server' debug configuration in case of a virtual machine dev setup
- Use debug over SSH
- extract PHPUnit files in a local directory

What was your solution?